# Dynamic side-by side tables in msword using xslt

Tags: xslt, ms-word

I'm using xslt to generate a Word document using FoundationPHP.  I'm trying to create a template that will dynamically create tables (max of 2 side by side tables per line) based on the number of items a user selects.

My prefered outcome would have the generated Word ducument appear like:

```
Table 1     Table 2

Table 3
```

I've tried placing the table in a text box and using a foreach command, but what I get is:

```
Table 1

Table 2

Table 3
```

I've also tried running the foreach command on the `<w:tc>` but get results like:

```
Table 1  Table 2 Table 3
```

My xslt code looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <-- Code for document properties
      <w:body>
          <w:tbl>
            <w:tblPr>
              <w:tblStyle w:val="TableGrid"/>
              <w:tblW w:w="2483" w:type="pct"/>
              <w:tblBorders>
                <w:top w:val="none" w:sz="0" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
                <w:left w:val="none" w:sz="0" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
                <w:bottom w:val="none" w:sz="0" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
                <w:right w:val="none" w:sz="0" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
                <w:insideH w:val="none" w:sz="0" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
                <w:insideV w:val="none" w:sz="0" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
              </w:tblBorders>
              <w:tblLook w:val="04A0" w:firstRow="1" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:noHBand="0" w:noVBand="1"/>
            </w:tblPr>
            <w:tblGrid>
              <w:gridCol w:w="4648"/>
            </w:tblGrid>
            <w:tr w:rsidR="00A00BC9" w:rsidTr="00A00BC9">               
        <xsl:for-each select="root/row">
              <w:tc>
                <w:tcPr>
                  <w:tcW w:w="4625" w:type="dxa"/>
                </w:tcPr>
                <w:tbl>
                  <w:tblPr>
                    <w:tblStyle w:val="TableGrid"/>
                    <w:tblW w:w="4320" w:type="dxa"/>
                    <w:tblBorders>
                      <w:top w:val="none" w:sz="0" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
                    </w:tblBorders>
                    <w:tblLook w:val="04A0" w:firstRow="1" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:noHBand="0" w:noVBand="1"/>
                  </w:tblPr>
                  <w:tblGrid>
                    <w:gridCol w:w="4363"/>
                  </w:tblGrid>
                  <w:tr w:rsidR="00A00BC9" w:rsidTr="00BD1383">
                    <w:trPr>
                      <w:trHeight w:val="3312"/>
                    </w:trPr>
                    <w:tc>
                      <w:tcPr>
                        <w:tcW w:w="4449" w:type="dxa"/>
                        <w:tcBorders>
                          <w:top w:val="single" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="1E4959"/>
                          <w:left w:val="single" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="1E4959"/>
                          <w:bottom w:val="single" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="1E4959"/>
                          <w:right w:val="single" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="1E4959"/>
                        </w:tcBorders>
                        <w:vAlign w:val="center"/>
                      </w:tcPr>
                      <w:p w:rsidR="00A00BC9" w:rsidRDefault="00A00BC9" w:rsidP="00A00BC9">
                        <w:pPr>
                          <w:spacing w:after="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
                          <w:jc w:val="center"/>
                        </w:pPr>
                        <w:r>
                          <w:rPr>
                            <w:noProof/>
                          </w:rPr>
                          <w:drawing>
<!--                            Code for image-->
                          </w:drawing>
                        </w:r>
                      </w:p>
                    </w:tc>
                  </w:tr>
                  <w:tr w:rsidR="00A00BC9" w:rsidTr="00BD1383">
                    <w:trPr>
                      <w:trHeight w:hRule="exact" w:val="144"/>
                    </w:trPr>
                    <w:tc>
                      <w:tcPr>
                        <w:tcW w:w="4449" w:type="dxa"/>
                        <w:tcBorders>
                          <w:top w:val="single" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="1E4959"/>
                          <w:left w:val="nil"/>
                          <w:bottom w:val="nil"/>
                          <w:right w:val="nil"/>
                        </w:tcBorders>
                        <w:vAlign w:val="center"/>
                      </w:tcPr>
                      <w:p w:rsidR="00A00BC9" w:rsidRDefault="00A00BC9" w:rsidP="00A00BC9">
                        <w:pPr>
                          <w:spacing w:after="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
                          <w:jc w:val="center"/>
                        </w:pPr>
                      </w:p>
                    </w:tc>
                  </w:tr>
                  <w:tr w:rsidR="00A00BC9" w:rsidTr="00BD1383">
                    <w:trPr>
                      <w:trHeight w:val="720"/>
                    </w:trPr>
                    <w:tc>
                      <w:tcPr>
                        <w:tcW w:w="4449" w:type="dxa"/>
                        <w:tcBorders>
                          <w:top w:val="nil"/>
                          <w:left w:val="nil"/>
                          <w:bottom w:val="nil"/>
                          <w:right w:val="nil"/>
                        </w:tcBorders>
                      </w:tcPr>
                      <w:p w:rsidR="00A00BC9" w:rsidRDefault="00A00BC9" w:rsidP="00A00BC9">
                        <w:pPr>
                          <w:spacing w:after="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
                          <w:jc w:val="center"/>
                          <w:rPr>
                            <w:rFonts w:cstheme="minorHAnsi"/>
                            <w:sz w:val="20"/>
                            <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
                          </w:rPr>
                        </w:pPr>
                        <w:r>
                          <w:rPr>
                            <w:rFonts w:cstheme="minorHAnsi"/>
                            <w:sz w:val="20"/>
                            <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
                          </w:rPr>
                          <w:t>Improved Sale <xsl:value-of select="rank"/></w:t>
                        </w:r>
                      </w:p>
                      <w:p w:rsidR="00A00BC9" w:rsidRPr="005F3377" w:rsidRDefault="00A00BC9" w:rsidP="00A00BC9">
                        <w:pPr>
                          <w:spacing w:after="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
                          <w:jc w:val="center"/>
                          <w:rPr>
                            <w:rFonts w:cstheme="minorHAnsi"/>
                            <w:sz w:val="20"/>
                            <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
                          </w:rPr>
                        </w:pPr>
                        <w:r>
                          <w:rPr>
                            <w:rFonts w:cstheme="minorHAnsi"/>
                            <w:sz w:val="20"/>
                            <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
                          </w:rPr>
                          <w:t xml:space="preserve"><xsl:value-of select="address"/>, <xsl:value-of select="city"/></w:t>
                        </w:r>
                      </w:p>
                    </w:tc>
                  </w:tr>
                </w:tbl>
                <w:p w:rsidR="00A00BC9" w:rsidRDefault="00A00BC9" w:rsidP="00A00BC9"/>
              </w:tc>
        </xsl:for-each>
              <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
              <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
            </w:tr>
          </w:tbl>        
        <w:p w:rsidR="00A00BC9" w:rsidRDefault="00A00BC9"/>
        <w:sectPr w:rsidR="00A00BC9">
          <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840"/>
          <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="720" w:footer="720" w:gutter="0"/>
          <w:cols w:space="720"/>
          <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
        </w:sectPr>
      </w:body>
    </w:document>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might put you on the track to a solution, definitely too big for a comment...

Are you able to use Nested Tables?

The table would look something like this:

[image]

And the relevant `.WordOpenXML` for this structure would be:

```
<w:body>
    <w:tbl>
        <w:tblPr>
            <w:tblStyle w:val="TableGrid"/>
            <w:tblW w:w="0" w:type="auto"/>
            <w:tblCellMar>
                <w:top w:w="85" w:type="dxa"/>
                <w:left w:w="85" w:type="dxa"/>
                <w:bottom w:w="85" w:type="dxa"/>
                <w:right w:w="85" w:type="dxa"/>
            </w:tblCellMar>
            <w:tblLook w:val="04A0" w:firstRow="1" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:noHBand="0" w:noVBand="1"/>
        </w:tblPr>
        <w:tblGrid>
            <w:gridCol w:w="4598"/>
            <w:gridCol w:w="4598"/>
        </w:tblGrid>
        <w:tr w:rsidR="00FE4524" w:rsidTr="00CE49DD">
            <w:tc>
                <w:tcPr>
                    <w:tcW w:w="9196" w:type="dxa"/>
                    <w:gridSpan w:val="2"/>
                </w:tcPr>
                <w:p w:rsidR="00FE4524" w:rsidRDefault="00FE4524" w:rsidP="00CE49DD"/>
            </w:tc>
        </w:tr>
        <w:tr w:rsidR="00FE4524" w:rsidTr="00CE49DD">
            <w:tc>
                <w:tcPr>
                    <w:tcW w:w="4598" w:type="dxa"/>
                </w:tcPr>
                <w:tbl>
                    <w:tblPr>
                        <w:tblStyle w:val="TableGrid"/>
                        <w:tblW w:w="0" w:type="auto"/>
                        <w:tblLook w:val="04A0" w:firstRow="1" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:noHBand="0" w:noVBand="1"/>
                    </w:tblPr>
                    <w:tblGrid>
                        <w:gridCol w:w="4413"/>
                    </w:tblGrid>
                    <w:tr w:rsidR="00FE4524" w:rsidTr="00CE49DD">
                        <w:tc>
                            <w:tcPr>
                                <w:tcW w:w="4413" w:type="dxa"/>
                            </w:tcPr>
                            <w:p w:rsidR="00FE4524" w:rsidRDefault="00FE4524" w:rsidP="00CE49DD"/>
                        </w:tc>
                    </w:tr>
                    <w:tr w:rsidR="00FE4524" w:rsidTr="00CE49DD">
                        <w:tc>
                            <w:tcPr>
                                <w:tcW w:w="4413" w:type="dxa"/>
                            </w:tcPr>
                            <w:p w:rsidR="00FE4524" w:rsidRDefault="00FE4524" w:rsidP="00CE49DD"/>
                        </w:tc>
                    </w:tr>
                </w:tbl>
                <w:p w:rsidR="00FE4524" w:rsidRDefault="00FE4524" w:rsidP="00CE49DD"/>
            </w:tc>
            <w:tc>
                <w:tcPr>
                    <w:tcW w:w="4598" w:type="dxa"/>
                </w:tcPr>
                <w:tbl>
                    <w:tblPr>
                        <w:tblStyle w:val="TableGrid"/>
                        <w:tblW w:w="0" w:type="auto"/>
                        <w:tblLook w:val="04A0" w:firstRow="1" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:noHBand="0" w:noVBand="1"/>
                    </w:tblPr>
                    <w:tblGrid>
                        <w:gridCol w:w="2206"/>
                        <w:gridCol w:w="2207"/>
                    </w:tblGrid>
                    <w:tr w:rsidR="00FE4524" w:rsidTr="00CE49DD">
                        <w:tc>
                            <w:tcPr>
                                <w:tcW w:w="2206" w:type="dxa"/>
                            </w:tcPr>
                            <w:p w:rsidR="00FE4524" w:rsidRDefault="00FE4524" w:rsidP="00CE49DD"/>
                        </w:tc>
                        <w:tc>
                            <w:tcPr>
                                <w:tcW w:w="2207" w:type="dxa"/>
                            </w:tcPr>
                            <w:p w:rsidR="00FE4524" w:rsidRDefault="00FE4524" w:rsidP="00CE49DD"/>
                        </w:tc>
                    </w:tr>
                    <w:tr w:rsidR="00FE4524" w:rsidTr="00CE49DD">
                        <w:tc>
                            <w:tcPr>
                                <w:tcW w:w="2206" w:type="dxa"/>
                            </w:tcPr>
                            <w:p w:rsidR="00FE4524" w:rsidRDefault="00FE4524" w:rsidP="00CE49DD"/>
                        </w:tc>
                        <w:tc>
                            <w:tcPr>
                                <w:tcW w:w="2207" w:type="dxa"/>
                            </w:tcPr>
                            <w:p w:rsidR="00FE4524" w:rsidRDefault="00FE4524" w:rsidP="00CE49DD"/>
                        </w:tc>
                    </w:tr>
                </w:tbl>
                <w:p w:rsidR="00FE4524" w:rsidRDefault="00FE4524" w:rsidP="00CE49DD"/>
            </w:tc>
        </w:tr>
        <w:tr w:rsidR="00FE4524" w:rsidTr="00CE49DD">
            <w:tc>
                <w:tcPr>
                    <w:tcW w:w="9196" w:type="dxa"/>
                    <w:gridSpan w:val="2"/>
                </w:tcPr>
                <w:p w:rsidR="00FE4524" w:rsidRDefault="00FE4524" w:rsidP="00CE49DD"/>
            </w:tc>
        </w:tr>
    </w:tbl>
    <w:p w:rsidR="00000000" w:rsidRDefault="00FE4524"/>
    <w:sectPr w:rsidR="00000000">
        <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840"/>
        <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="720" w:footer="720" w:gutter="0"/>
        <w:cols w:space="720"/>
    </w:sectPr>
</w:body>
```

Comment: Also this link may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3618665/3451115

Comment: I didn't even think of using nested tables.  I'll try that out.

Comment: Cool, if you get it working It'd  be great if you can also share the XSLT - cheers

Comment: I wanted to accept this answer as the nested table led me in the right direction.  If you want to see how it was done, go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51330158/problems-with-data-alignment-in-xslt-with-nested-tables as I pasted a general idea of how this was done, although I still have an issue with how the data is coming in.

Comment: The other question has an answer that didn't work for my data issue, but I did finally figure out a solution.

Comment: I'd be keen to see what you ended up doing. You ~can~ might be able to post your own solution, or edit a solution that helped you. I'll +1 both your questions to help you get the rep...