# Problems with data alignment in XSLT with nested tables

Tags: xml, xslt, ms-word

I'm generating a Word document via FoundationPHP using XSLT and nested tables.

My desired results would be:

```
Table 1        Table 2
Image 1        Image 2
Label 1        Label 2
Data 1         Data 2

Table 3        Table 4
Image 3        Image 4
Label 3        Label 4
Data 3         Data 4

Table 5
Image 5
Label 5
Data 5
```

However, what I am getting is:

```
Table 1        Table 2
Image 1        Image 2
Label 1        Label 2
Label 1        Label 4

Table 3        Table 4
Image 3        Image 4
Label 3        Label 4
Data 2        Label 5

Table 5
Image 5
Label 5
Data 3
```

My XSLT code (simplified for posting purposes)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:w="http://some.bla">      <!-- Namespace of 'w' added by edit -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <w:document>             <!-- Added by edit !!! -->
            blah
            <w:body>
                <w:tbl>
                    <xsl:variable name="size" select="count(root/row)"/>

                    <xsl:for-each name="count" select="root/row[ceiling($size div 2) &gt;= position()]">
                        <xsl:variable name="level0Count" select="position()"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="imageid" select="position()+1"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="level1Count" select="position() - 1"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="level2Count" select="$level1Count * 2 + position()"/>
                        <w:tr w:rsidR="003346C6" w:rsidTr="003346C6">
                            <w:tc>
                                <w:tcPr>
                                    <w:tcW w:w="4648" w:type="dxa"/>
                                </w:tcPr>
                                <w:tbl>
                                    <w:tr w:rsidR="003346C6" w:rsidTr="00BD1383">
                                        <w:tc>
                                            <w:p w:rsidR="003346C6" w:rsidRDefault="003346C6" w:rsidP="003346C6">
                                                <w:r>
                                                    Image 1
                                                </w:r>
                                            </w:p>
                                        </w:tc>
                                    </w:tr>
                                    <w:tr w:rsidR="003346C6" w:rsidTr="00BD1383">
                                        <w:tc>
                                            <w:p w:rsidR="003346C6" w:rsidRPr="0004412A" w:rsidRDefault="003346C6" w:rsidP="003346C6">
                                                <w:r w:rsidRPr="0004412A">
                                                    <xsl:choose>
                                                        <xsl:when test="position()=1">
                                                            <w:t>Label <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                                                                <w:b />
                                                            </w:t>
                                                        </xsl:when>
                                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                                            <w:t>Label <xsl:value-of select="2*position()-1"/>
                                                                <w:b />
                                                            </w:t>
                                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                                    </xsl:choose>
                                                </w:r>
                                            </w:p>
                                            <w:p w:rsidR="003346C6" w:rsidRPr="005F3377" w:rsidRDefault="003346C6" w:rsidP="003346C6">
                                                <w:r>
                                                    <w:t>
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="Data"/>
                                                    </w:t>
                                                </w:r>
                                                <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
                                                <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
                                            </w:p>
                                        </w:tc>
                                    </w:tr>
                                </w:tbl>
                                <w:p w:rsidR="003346C6" w:rsidRDefault="003346C6" w:rsidP="003346C6"/>
                            </w:tc>
                            <xsl:if test="following::row[ceiling($size div 2)]/data!=''">
                                <w:tc>
                                    <w:tcPr>
                                        <w:tcW w:w="4648" w:type="dxa"/>
                                    </w:tcPr>
                                    <w:tbl>
                                        <w:tr w:rsidR="003346C6" w:rsidTr="00BD1383">
                                            <w:tc>
                                                <w:p w:rsidR="003346C6" w:rsidRDefault="003346C6" w:rsidP="003346C6">
                                                    <w:r>
                                                        Image 2
                                                    </w:r>
                                                </w:p>
                                            </w:tc>
                                        </w:tr>
                                        <w:tr w:rsidR="003346C6" w:rsidTr="00BD1383">
                                            <w:tc>
                                                <w:p w:rsidR="003346C6" w:rsidRDefault="003346C6" w:rsidP="003346C6">
                                                    <w:r>
                                                        <xsl:choose>
                                                            <xsl:when test="position()=1">
                                                                <w:t>
                                                                    Label <xsl:value-of select="position()+1"/>
                                                                </w:t>
                                                            </xsl:when>
                                                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                                                <xsl:if test="following::row[ceiling($size div 2)]/data!=''">
                                                                    <w:t>
                                                                        Label <xsl:value-of select="2*position()"/>
                                                                    </w:t>
                                                                </xsl:if>
                                                            </xsl:otherwise>
                                                        </xsl:choose>
                                                    </w:r>
                                                </w:p>
                                                <w:p w:rsidR="003346C6" w:rsidRPr="005F3377" w:rsidRDefault="003346C6" w:rsidP="003346C6">
                                                    <w:r>
                                                        <w:t>
                                                            <xsl:value-of select="following::row[ceiling($size div 2)]/data"/>
                                                        </w:t>
                                                    </w:r>
                                                </w:p>
                                            </w:tc>
                                        </w:tr>
                                    </w:tbl>
                                    <w:p w:rsidR="003346C6" w:rsidRDefault="003346C6" w:rsidP="003346C6"/>
                                </w:tc>

                            </xsl:if>
                        </w:tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </w:tbl>
                <w:p w:rsidR="00A00BC9" w:rsidRDefault="00A00BC9"/>
            </w:body>
        </w:document>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see, the image and the label are correct, however the data is coming in vertically.  I've been staring at this code to the point where my double vision is making me second guess everything.

EDIT:  This is the XML output from my script.  (I only included 3 rows)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <row>
        <id>10755</id>
        <image>10755/11786.jpg</image>
        <data> 8220 Southwest Warm Springs Street</data>
    </row>
    <row>
        <id>10493</id>
        <image>10493/11786.jpg</image>
        <data> 21101-21149 SW 115th Avenue</data>
    </row>
    <row>
        <id>11008</id>
        <image>11008/11786.jpg</image>
        <data> 7144 NW Progress Court</data>
    </row>
</root>
```

To make the question more complete, here is the code to get the data:

```
if ( isset( $_GET[ 'id' ] ) ) {
    $sql = "SELECT ID, data, image FROM property WHERE ID in (" . $_GET['id'] .") ORDER BY field(ID," . $_GET['id'] .")";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    if ($db->error) {
        $error = $db->error;
    }
}
}

function getRow($result) {
    return $result->fetch_assoc();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the source XML?

Comment: The xml is generated via a mysql script:
` SELECT ID, data,  image
FROM property
WHERE ID in (" . $_GET['id'] .")
   ORDER BY field(ID," . $_GET['id'] .") `

Comment: That doesn't help. We need (any) source XML for the XSLT. This would complete a [mcve].

Comment: No problem.  Give me about 10 minutes to get the XML.

Comment: Just FYI: You can edit your question to include the XML.

Comment: XML Output added to question

Comment: I edited you XML and XSLT to be _well-formed_. I added a namespace declaration and an element to your XSLT and indented your XML. Now we may have a [mcve]. I still don't see how the output of the XSLT results in your text samples.

Comment: The XSLT file is converted to XML and replaces the document.xml inside of a MSWord.docx file (Using FoundationPHP).  The output is the second bock of code I posted.  If you want, I could extract the xml from the generated Word document, however, I have been down voted in the past for providing too much information in questions before, so you can understand my concern with adding much to the question. 

(Crazy thing is, I never get upvoted for providing all the information needed, just down voted if I miss one item or add too much information

Comment: The problem is that I (and probably others) cannot reproduce the generation chain from XML+XSLT to the (actual or desired) text output. So I can hardly help you, because I cannot reproduce (and possibly fix) your output.

Comment: I could provide the code for FoundationPHP, but that will certainly make this page far too long.  Aside from doing that, I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first call to data, change to

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="position()=1">
    <w:t><xsl:value-of select="data"/></w:t>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <w:t><xsl:value-of select="following::row[$imageid - 2]/data"/></w:t>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Then, on your second call, use

```
    <w:t><xsl:value-of select="following::row[$imageid - 1]/data"/></w:t>
```

This should line up the data the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

If the aim is to map the sequence of `row` elements (i.e. row 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) to a two column table where each table cell contains the data of a a row and the layout is

```
<table>
  <row><cell>1</cell><cell>2</cell></row>
  <row><cell>3</cell><cell>4</cell></row>
  <row><cell>5</cell></row>
</table>
```

then I think that is easy by processing the odd rows to map them to a table row and then build the two cells in each row by processing that odd row plus its immediately following sibling and then if needed map each row to a nested table presenting the data of an input `row` element.

Here is an example using HTML tables as the target format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    exclude-result-prefixes="exsl msxml"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="5" doctype-system="about:legacy-doctype"/>


  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>.NET XSLT Fiddle Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="root">
      <table>
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>col 1</th>
                  <th>col 2</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="row[position() mod 2 = 1]" mode="row"/>
          </tbody>
      </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row" mode="row">
      <tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::row[1]" mode="cell"/>
      </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row" mode="cell">
      <td>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="table"/>
      </td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row" mode="table">
      <table>
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Table <xsl:number/></th>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="th"/>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr>
                  <td><xsl:number/></td>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row/*" mode="th">
      <th>
          <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
      </th>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row/*">
      <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </td>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row/image">
      <td>
          Image <xsl:number count="row"/> <img src="{.}" alt="image"/>
      </td>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKwi

Of course the result elements need to be adjusted to your target markup language but the algorithm should be the same, the only problem left is to make sure an empty cell is added to the last table row in case there is an odd number of input `row` elements and the target layout does not work or looks awful with missing cell. This is easily done by changing one template to

```
  <xsl:template match="row" mode="row">
      <tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::row[1]" mode="cell"/>
          <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::row)">
              <td></td>
          </xsl:if>
      </tr>
  </xsl:template>
```

as done in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKwi/1

Comment: This looks very interesting.  It will take me a couple of hours to implement it with my data, and as soon as I test it, I'll let you know.

Comment: Sadly, this didn't work for my MS-Word issue (I did change the tags from html).